# Firestore query documents by birthday date, like only query by day and month exclude year?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have users collection where each user contains its `birthday` filed as `Timestamp`, so now I want to query users whose birthday is **today**, so how can I query only for `day` and `month` because in this case `year` does not matter.
[image]

So what I know is that we can only search by date like this  `firestore.collection("user").whereEqualTo("birhtday", todaysDate)`, but as we know it's not going to return anything because it will also going to match `year`

So what would be best solution here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since passing a `Date` object as the second argument to the following query:

```
firestore.collection("user").whereEqualTo("birhtday", todaysDate);
```

Return all users that have the birthday today, the addition of a new property is required. In this new property you can simply store the date as day and month in a String format:

```
shortBirhtday: "09-Jun"
```

And then query the database using:

```
firestore.collection("user").whereEqualTo("shortBirhtday", "09-Jun");
```

This query ill return all users that have the birthday on 9 June, no matter of year.

**Edit:**

According to @DougStevenson comment, a more appropriate way of storing the Date should be:

```
09-06
```

Where `09` stands for the day and `06` stands for the month. And this is the corresponding query:

```
firestore.collection("user").whereEqualTo("shortBirhtday", "09-06");
```

Comment: Yes, currently looks like this is the only workaround, i'm also planing to add two fields for `day` and `month` inside user document.

Comment: Yes, that's a quite common solution. I don't think it's necessary to add two properties since only one will to do the job ;)

Comment: hmm, i also think i have to create one because for two i guess i have to create indexes(not sure)

Comment: If you'll use two properties, you'll need an index only if you sort the restuls, otherwise there is no need for an index. But to keep things simple, it's better to use only one property.

Comment: Please note that not every language uses "Jun" as an abbreviation for June.  It would be better to use a number.

Comment: thanks @DougStevenson and Alex, i have already used numbers for month and  date.

Comment: As a related update, anyone has some good library for date string formatting?